# How to set a timeout for both connection and socket in axios?

Tags: node.js, axios

I have a very simple app which requests a JSON using axios:

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get("https://dummyjson.com/products/1", {
    signal: AbortSignal.timeout(1000),
    timeout: 1000
});
```

I know that the `timeout` property is only taking care of response timeout after the socket has been established. To handle timeouts with connection issues, I am using `AbortSignal` based on this article: https://timmousk.com/blog/axios-timeout/

However when I run this script in a loop, there are always some requests (2-3 in a 100) which fails with `ERR_CANCELED` after 1 second (expected), but the whole function takes exactly 5 seconds to finish. I would like to avoid this, and kill the request after exactly 1 second.

What am I missing?